# Data Validation in C when the user inputs an incorrect value to avoid program crash

Tags: c, int, user-input, scanf, validation

How do I ensure that the user inputs only an integer value so that the program wont crash?

If the user inputs anything else than an integer, I want to:
printf("Please re-check your entry);

```
printf("How many values do you want to enter? \t");
    int g;
    scanf("%d", &g);
```

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: Also you'll probably want to flush the rest of the line after detecting invalid input. There must be a good duplicate of this

Comment: There must be quite a lot of other questions that this is a duplicate of.  Some of them might be listed in the related questions, but none of those strikes me as likely to be the 'canonical' answer.

Comment: You will need to check the return value from `scanf()`, and wrap the code in a loop, and probably arrange to gobble the rest of the line of input if the conversion fails (because you might need to skip past them typing `thirty-three` where you intended them to type `33`).  You should distinguish between 'conversion failed' (0) and end of file (EOF).

Answer (score 2):

I would say, check the return value of scanf:

> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.
>
> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the error.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to say that you have to make some custom validation to check if whether `scanf` read integer or not.

Also i advise to use `fgets`(There is no bounds checking in `scanf()`)

you can do something like this

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int validate ( char *a )
{
  unsigned x;
  for ( x = 0; x < strlen ( a ); x++ )
    if ( !isdigit ( a[x] ) ) return 1;
  return 0;
}

int main ( void )
{
  int i;
  char buffer[BUFSIZ];
  printf ( "Enter a number: " );
  if ( fgets ( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) != NULL ) {
    buffer[strlen ( buffer ) - 1] = '\0';
    if ( validate ( buffer ) == 0 ) {
      i = atoi ( buffer );
      printf ( "%d\n", i );
    }
    else
      printf ( "Error: Input validation\n" );
  }
  else
    printf ( "Error reading input\n" );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't allow leading or trailing spaces, nor plus or minus signs.  Whether that matters is another issue.

Comment: Depending on the input and on the platform used, this code may invoke undefined behavior. Note that the parameter for the function [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) is of type `int`, not `char`. According to the documentation of that function, calling that function with an argument whose value is not representable as `unsigned char` and is not the value `EOF` will invoke undefined behavior. Therefore, for platforms on which `char` is signed (which is most platforms), certain input will invoke undefined behavior. You should cast the argument to `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int num;
        printf("Enter the number\n");

        if((scanf("%d",&num)) == 1){ // checking return value of scanf here!

                printf(": %d\n",num);
                // do your stuff here
        }
        else
                printf("Please recheck your input!\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Here If the input is properly read and assigned `scanf` will return 1, else it will return 0.

Sample output-

```
root@sathish1:~/My Docs/Programs# ./a.out 
Enter the number
2
: 2
root@sathish1:~/My Docs/Programs# ./a.out 
Enter the number
asd
Please recheck your input!
```

Comment: However, a user input like `23hahaha` will probably be accepted (and understood as 23). I don't know if that matters to the OP.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch If that is the case, we need to scan the input in string format have to check each byte! if it is `int` then we can convert it using `atoi`!